# Why are Branch links are not deep linking from Facebook app on Android?

Tags: android, facebook, branch, deep-linking

I have integrated Branch in my Android app for deep linking and I'm having an issue. The issue is:

On clicking Branch URL from Facebook app's older version (v3.3) works & deep link data is returned in referringParams, but on clicking same Branch URL from Facebook app's latest version (v30.0.0.19.17) deep link data is not returned in referringParams.

I have an iOS version of my Android app with Branch integrated and everything works fine on iOS.

I also have a Facebook app for my Android & iOS apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook (around April 8th) updated the way their internal Webview handles URI schemes. They actually stripped out Branch referral data because they implemented App Links correctly. **You'll need to upgrade to Branch v 1.4.5 and implement a few extra things.**

From Branch's documentation, you'll see:

*Branch uses the Facebook App Links protocol to pass the deep links through to your app from Facebook. Funny enough, if you also have a Facebook app configured in the developer portal and you choose 'Deep link from feed', Facebook ignores it's own protocol. Make sure to uncheck this option in your Facebook app.*

Then, **you'll need to add a permission inside your manifest, and hook into `onNewIntent` inside your Activity**. More information here: https://github.com/branchmetrics/branch-android-sdk#important-migration-to-v145

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: What are the other implications of unchecking the "Deep link from feed" setting in Facebook apps?  What will happen to non-Branch deep links shared on Facebook?

Comment: The deep link from Facebook for the activity class name specified in Facebook app console will not work.

I think you would have got the solution but still answering if you haven't.